# Nav divider how do I have them display in CSS

Tags: html, css, nav, divider

[enter link description here](http://www.pengespill.eu/topmenu.gif)

Can you tell me how do I make the dividers from this menu ?

Comment: It should use left and right borders

Comment: show your code.. so that we can help you

Comment: a sketch or ur current code.

Answer (score 3):

something like

```css
ul{
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background: #000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
ul > li{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
ul > li:first-child{
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}
ul > li a{
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wrx26qsp/3/)**

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Test Text</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Test Text</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Test Text</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Test Text</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```